# Flattening a control flow graph to structured code

Tags: compiler-construction, compilation, theory, control-flow, control-flow-graph

I would like to render a control flow graph (CFG) out to high-level code. Normally this is very easy; walk the tree, render each basic block in turn, glue it all together with gotos.

Unfortunately, gotos are out of fashion these days, and most modern languages don't support them. So I need some way to glue my basic blocks together using only those control flow statements that exist in the language: `for`, `while`, `do`...`while`, `if`, `break` and `continue`. (I'm not willing to consider building a state machine using variables.)

It would appear that while there are algorithms to do this, they will *not* work in every case. That is, it's possible to construct a CFG that cannot be flattened to structured code using only the above limited set of control flow structures.

This seems intuitively obvious to me, but I can't prove it (and the documentation for the algorithms I've found don't go into more detail). And I haven't been able to find an example of a CFG which can't be flattened like this.

I would like to know, definitively, if this is possible or not.

Option (a): does anyone have a example of a CFG which cannot be flattened as described above? (Which will tell me that it's not possible.)

Option (b): does anyone have a proof that CFGs *can* be flattened as described above? (Which will tell me that it *is* possible.) An algorithm to do it would be highly desirable, too, as I would then have to make it work...

Comment: Why not build a state machine using variables? Just because you didn't mention it... are you aware of the structured programming theorem?

Comment: State machines using variables are dead slow. That's what I'm looking at right now, but some simple benchmarks show that I'm wasting about 30% of the CPU time just shuffling state. Plus, I already know how to do that, so don't need to ask about it here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I have a result.

The answer seems to be: it is not possible. This is from *Communications of the ACM*, volume 9, pages 366 to 371 in a paper from 1966 called "Flow Diagrams, Turing Machines and Languages with only Two Formation Rules" by Giuseppe Jacopini. [CiteSeer link.](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.119.9119) (Which, amusingly, I found referenced from Knuth's seminal (and, from my point of view, incredibly annoying) *Go To Statement Considered Harmful*.)

Disappointingly, they don't have a proof, saying they were unable to find one.

The good news is that the paper does describe a strategy for converting an arbitrary CFG into a CFG using only limited control-flow mechanisms in an efficient fashion, using as little state as possible. The paper is pretty hard going but it looks promising.

Comment: The computer scientist who wrote the letter suggesting that the use of **goto** be limited was Edsger Dijkstra. Donald Knuth was and afaik is still a defender of **goto** although he, too, believes it should be used with some restraint. The difference between their views was never as dramatic as it is often portrayed, and the debate is not helped by Manichean exaggerations, which are tragically prevalent in modern discourse in general.

Answer (score 4):

although this question was asked a long time ago this actually seems to be possible. Mozilla had a similar problem when compiling LLVM to JS (or now WebAssembly). JS and WebAssembly only allow structured control flow, while LLVM allows arbitrary control flow.

They'v written a paper about this which is also used for [WebAssembly](https://github.com/WebAssembly/design/issues/33):

> This idea is modeled on the [Relooper](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/raw/master/docs/paper.pdf) algorithm from [2011](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2048224). There is a proof there that any control flow can be represented in a structured way, using just the available control flow constructs in JavaScript, and using a helper variable like label mentioned in the Tilt semantics, without any code duplication (other approaches split nodes, and have bad worst-case code size situations). The relooper has also been implemented in Emscripten, and over the last 4 years we have gotten a lot of practical experience with it, showing that it gives good results in practice, typically with little usage of the helper variable.

Comment: I've looked at Relooper. It uses a bunch of heuristics to try to reconstruct what it can, but it's pretty easy to confuse, at which point it falls back to constructing a state machine. It's strictly a pragmatic, good-enough-for-government work solution, rather than a real solution to the fundamental problem.

Answer (score 0):

If the Control Flow Graph is not [*reducible*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control-flow_graph#Reducibility), then it cannot be "flattened" to structured control flow as you describe. Any irreducable CFG contains some variant of the following

[image: Irreducable Control Flow Graph]

Here both `y` and `z` are loops that enter each other, which would be impossible to create with normal structured control flow.

However, most Control Flow Graphs *can* be converted. You can use the auxiliary data structure the Dominator Tree to do this. See [this implementation](https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/3547621) in Haskell for example.

Comment: The above graph, while irreducible, can be implemented with structured control flow with the addition of a helper variable, say "jump". We add a block w above x which sets jump=false and goes to x. Then we create a new block v that sets jump=true, and direct the right edge coming out of x to v instead of to z. Then we direct v, x, and z to a new block u, with a condition if jump=true, y else z. Then the first statement of z added to set jump = false. This adds a minimum of code with no duplication and turns this structure into a loop with a single entry.

Answer (score 0):

[image: irreducible graph]

The above graph, while irreducible, can be implemented with structured control flow with the addition of a helper variable, say "jump". We add a block w above x which sets jump=false and goes to x. Then we create a new block v that sets jump=true, and direct the right edge coming out of x to v instead of to z. Then we direct v, x, and z to a new block u, with a condition if jump=true, z else y. Then the first statement of z added to set jump = false. This adds a minimum of code with no duplication and turns this structure into a loop with a single entry.

Reducing irreducible control flow:

[image: reducing irreducible flow]

Comment: Adding state produces a different CFG, meaning it's out of scope for me. (Also, from the practical point of view, adding state nerfs the ability of the compiler to reason about the program, resulting in much worse code generation.)

Comment: In that case it is impossible. Note that this situation cannot be created by structured elements either. It takes a go to. It's rare in the real world, because you need something like if x, go to y else z, y, go to z.